# How to fetch the current html page visited and store in php my sql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need the currently viewed page to be stored in **php mysql**. I have a single line of html page and i need to store the data like if users visit **about us** then the url followed by about. Since it is a single html page *index.html* and all the menus are provided within that *index.html*

I already have a **db** and **PHP** code but did not work as expected

```
 $page = "https://chennaifreelancers.com".$_SERVER['HTTPS_HOST']."".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

I tried

```
$page="https://chennaifreelancers.com".$_SERVER['HTTPS_HOST']."".$_SERVER['index.html'];
```

and

```
$page="https://chennaifreelancers.com".$_SERVER['HTTPS_HOST']."".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Included this as well in my html page

```
<header class="bgimg-1 w3-display-container w3-grayscale-min" id="home" form method="post" action="get_details.php">
```

PHP Version: 5.5 and Maria DB: 10.2

```
#get_details.php

<?php
// require ReCaptcha class

  require_once("DBConfig.php");

 $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 $page= https://chennaifreelancers.com".$_SERVER['HTTPS_HOST']."".$_SERVER['index.html'];
 $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
 $datetime = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
 $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


$query = mysql_query("SELECT `ip` FROM `visitors_table` WHERE `ip` = '$ip' ");
if(mysql_num_rows($query)> 0) { // if return 1, email exist.

} else { // else not, insert to the table

  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `visitors_table` (`ip` ,`current_page`,`referrer`,`time` ,`user_agent`)
                            VALUES ('$ipaddress','$page','$referrer','$datetime','$useragent')");


    $result=mysql_query($query);




     $result=mysql_query($query);




    } 



 close($query);
```

Actual : https://chennaifreelancers.com/get_details.php  this is recorded in the DB but

Expected: https://chennaifreelancers.com/#about etc i require this to be stored in DB

Answer (score 0):

You could do with ajax call while [`hashchange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) event

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", store, false);
```

```js
function store() {
  //call get_details.php via ajax call
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "get_details.php",
    success: function(response) {
      $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you share how i include this in ajax call . Where should i include this get_details.php in the above function.

Comment: Do I need to call this function in my each page ??<!-- -->

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#display").click(function() {                

      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to display.php
        type: "post",
        url: "get_details.php",             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                    
            $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
            //alert(response);
        }

    });
});
});

</script>

<!--/-->